# F# Script Ends Immediately After Execution (FSI)

Tags: winforms, f#, f#-interactive

When I double-click .fsx files the script ends immediately after execution. There is no chance of interacting with the script or see what it does.

I can barely see one of the scripts create a WinForms window, but it quickly closes.

I have tried several default Run actions (including sending to a .cmd file):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.1\Framework\v4.0\fsi.exe" "%1" %*
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.1\Framework\v4.0\fsi.exe" --quiet --exec "%1"
```

Comment: What happens when you run it from the command line?

Comment: That's what scripts are supposed to do: execute and be done. Why would you expect them to hang around?

Comment: When run from the command line it exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: If I run a "Hello World!" script, I want to see the output in the console. Is "printf" output only for compiled code?

Comment: --exec  Instructs F# interactive to exit after loading the files or running the script file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both command lines you tried do indeed run the script and then exit. If you want to keep the REPL open to interact with the script, you need either `--load:file.fsx` or `--use:file.fsx`.

- `--use:file.fsx` does roughly the same as just running fsi and then pasting the contents of `file.fsx` into the REPL. So for example if the file just contains `let x = 2` then you can immediately type `x;;` and it will be recognized. This is the one you want if your file contains a bunch of values, statements, types and/or modules.
- `--load:file.fsx` does roughly the same as just running fsi and typing `#load "file.fsx"`. This means that values defined in this file will be in a separate namespace. This is the one you want if your file starts with a `namespace` or `module` declaration.

Comment: Do I use the switch exactly as written above? Or do I replace "file.fsx" with "%1" (or similar wildcard)? I'm using the command for the default Run action for script files ("fsx" file type).

Comment: Well you put your filename instead of "file.fsx", so yeah here you need to put "%1".

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.1\Framework\v4.0\fsi.exe" --load:"%1" %*

Comment: You can exit the REPL with Ctrl+D (Windows).